# UIImageView animation has long delay on device

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I create a 5-frame animation on UImageView and each image is created by [UIImage imageWithContentOfFile:xxx], 
however, the animation on simulator is working well but not on device, it usually has ~1 sec delay though the animation duration is 1sec.

This is my code.

```
NSArray *animations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"ShakeAnimation"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[animations objectAtIndex:0]]];
imgView.tag = 10;
NSMutableArray *animationImgs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( NSString *path in animations )
{
    [animationImgs addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
}
[imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
[imgView setAnimationImages:animationImgs];
[imgView setAnimationDuration:1];
[animationImgs release];
```

and when the view controller recieved shack event, it calls [imgView startAnimation];

Is anyway to preload the images involved in the animation? thanks.

Comment: please show the code where u are passing the images to imageview for animation

Comment: And what's the source of your image files? File System or something like Web?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

If you want to preload the `UIImageView` animation images, just call `[imgView startAnimating]` after initialization. It seemed to work for me.

Comment: Just to mention - The actual function is startAnimating not startAnimation.